# Help understanding occupation numbers and configurations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, electrons, quantum-states

I'm reading Griffiths Introduction to Quantum Mechanics and on page 230 he speaks about 3 non-interacting particles. These particles have their own principal quantum numbers. The total energy is $E=E_A+E_B+E_C=\frac{\pi ^2 \hbar ^2}{2ma^2}(n_A^2+n_B^2+n_C^2)$.

I'm confused with the next bit. He says to pretend for a moment that $E=363(\frac{\pi ^2 \hbar ^2}{2ma^2})$. This means that $(n_A^2+n_B^2+n_C^2)=363$. So he finds what numbers combine to make 363. He then lays them out like this:

[image]

My questions:

1. At the top of the image where all the combinations are laid out, is each **group** of 3 numbers a **quantum state**? So in the first line there is 1 quantum state, in the 2nd there are 3, etc...?
2. Is the occupation number therefore 3 for all of these states? Because if each thing in parentheses is a state, then the total number of particles in each state is always 3.
3. Why are configurations comprised of an infinite set of zeroes?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. At the top of the image where all the combinations are laid out, is each group of 3 numbers a quantum state? So in the first line there is 1 quantum state, in the 2nd there are 3, etc...?

If the particles were distinguishable then yes, each state tuple would be a distinct state. Remember what those tuples mean, each entry in the tuple carries a complete set of quantum numbers to distinguish the state for one particle in the system. Since we are working with infinite wells here, the energy level completely specifies the quantum state, so we have one number for each particle (you could imagine a tuple with 3-vector at each entry for a hydrogen atom, for instance).

For clarity, call the first entry in the tuple the "red" particle and the second entry the "blue particle". If these were different particles, then red being in energy level 1 and blue being in energy level 2 would be a different state, but since these particles are *indistinguishable*, there is no difference between (red in 1, blue in 2) and (red in 2, blue in 1).

To actually construct the wave function, we'd need to know whether we have bosons or fermions. The actual state vector would be (anti)symmetric combination of all the possibilities listed in the rows above for (fermions)bosons. **Note:** We have Bosons here because Griffiths is including states with more than one particle at the same energy level.

That is to say, for indistinguishable particles each line above is one and only one state, but you must enumerate all the possibilities in order to actually construct the wave function. As an example, the normalized second row wave function for bosons (using the tuple notation):

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}((13,13,5) + (13,5,13) + (5,13,13)) $$

Using the, perhaps more familiar, notation of wavefunctions you have:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(\psi_{13}(x_1)\psi_{13}(x_2)\psi_5(x_3)+ \psi_{13}(x_1)\psi_5(x_2)\psi_{13}(x_3) + \psi_5(x_1)\psi_{13}(x_2)\psi_{13}(x_3)) $$

> 2. Is the occupation number therefore 3 for all of these states? Because if each thing in parentheses is a state, then the total number of particles in each state is always 3.

There are always 3 particles in your system, occupation number normally refers to a state. For instance, in the example above, the occupation number for the $n=13$ state is 2, and the occupation number for the $n=5$ state is 1.

> 3. Why are configurations comprised of an infinite set of zeroes?

The energy spectrum for the infinite well has infinitely many states, one for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This is just accounting.

Comment: Very good answer but I'm still confused with the **terminology**. I originally thought that the tuples in parentheses are called states (as Griffiths calls them). But now that I'm wrapping my head around this a little bit better, I think they are actually the configurations because they essentially say the same thing as the infinite zeroes thing.

Comment: I know that if an electron has a certain energy, then its quantum number defines that energy and therefore it is in state $\psi_n$. But I hesitate to call the tuple a quantum state....unless I can talk about the quantum state of the *system*?

Comment: 'Quantum state' normally just means an element of the Hilbert space that spans the solutions of your wave equation. You can definitely talk about the wavefunction of the 'whole system,' and you're right to realize that it's somehow different from the wavefunction of individual pieces. However, calling the tuple a wavefunction is totally fine as well; it's just a notation, in one to one correspondence with the more canonical 'wave function notation' I used above.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. At the top of the image where all the combinations are laid out, is
>      each group of 3 numbers a quantum state? So in the first line there is
>      1 quantum state, in the 2nd there are 3, etc...?

Each tuple of three numbers, such as $(13,13,5)$, is a state. In this state, particle #1 is in energy eigenstate $13$, particle #2 is in eigenstate $13$, and particle #3 is in eigenstate $5$. The state $(13,13,5)$ is a **product state**, meaning that it represents the state of a combination of systems\particles (a full description of the combination should also include the entangled states). Each particle has its own state in its own system represented by it own Hilbert space, but looking at the three particles combined as one system, with one Hilbert space, the state of the system as whole is described by $(13,13,5)$.

Now, the question of whether $(13,13,5)$ is different than $(13,5,13)$ or $(5,13,13)$ depends on whether the particles are distinguishable *in principal*. If there is no experiment or no sense in which we can assign each particle with a unique label, following it and at all times treating the label as an indicator of its identity, then the particles are said to be indistinguishable. In other words, if there is no physical consequence of swapping two of the particles at any time, then they are indistinguishable, and thus the states $(13,13,5)$, $(13,5,13)$, $(5,13,13)$ are all actually the same state. More generally, the states $(a,b,c)$ and $(d,e,f)$ are the same state if the set of numbers $\{a,b,c\}$ is equal to the set of numbers $\{d,e,f\}$, regardless of order (and allowing repetitions of elements in the set). **In the indistinguishable case, it doesn't matter which particle is in which energy eigenstate, since this has no meaning. It only matters how many particles are in each energy eigenstate** (also super-positions are allowed).

So a better way of describing the state of the combined system is by saying how many particles are in each state. In $(13,13,5)$, this is "$1$ particle in state $5$, $2$ particles in state $13$". We can write this, instead of using words, using the following notation:  $(o_1,o_2,o_3,...)$ represents the state that has $o_1$ particles in state $1$, $o_2$ particles in state $2$, and so on. The numbers $o_i$ are called **occupation numbers**. This notation works for any number of indistinguishable particles, not just three.

> 2. Is the occupation number therefore 3 for all of these states? Because if each thing in parentheses is a state, then the total number of particles in each state is always 3.

Following the explanation given above, the occupation numbers of $(13,13,5)$, for example, are $0$ for all state other than $13$ and $5$, $1$ for the state $5$, and $2$ for the state $13$.

> 3. Why are configurations comprised of an infinite set of zeroes?

Because for each state describing a finite number of particles, there is an infinite number of energy eigenstates not occupied, in other words, occupied with $0$ particles.

Comment: After writing this answer, I see that didn't make sure to specify exactly whether I use the word "state" for describing the state of the combined system or the state of each particle's separate system. @DarthVoid, if you find this confusing, please let me know. It should be clear by the context, though, I hope.